# How to change the main font in ClassicThesis without altering anything else

Tags: fonts, classicthesis, arsclassica

I'm using ClassicThesis plus Arsclassica packages and I would like to change the main font with a standard computer modern and at the same time, I don't want to change Headers style, Toc style or anything else. I have partially achieved this with the ClassicThesis option: `palatino=false`, but now the Toc font is switched in computer modern while I want the default style of Arsclassica. Any suggestion?

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openright,titlepage,headinclude,
footinclude,BCOR5mm,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{subfig} 

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,beramono,pdfspacing,palatino=false]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
%\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,eurosym,mathtools,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{tableposition=top,figureposition=bottom,font=small}
%\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}


\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \printfield{doi}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}{%
        \usebibmacro{eprint}%
    }{}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iffieldundef{doi}{%
        \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
    {}%
}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}\bibhyperref{\printfield{extrayear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\bibhyperref{\printfield{year}}\bibhyperref{\printfield{extrayear}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand*{\AC@hyperlink}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
    \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup
    }%
}
\makeatother

\date{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}    
\chapter*{Introduzione}
\lipsum
\chapter{Dummy title 1}
\lipsum
\section{Dummy title 2}
\lipsum
\chapter{Dummy title 3}
\lipsum
\section{Dummy title 4}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here what I obtain (please note Introduction and section titles are in cm font while chapter I think is the default iwona with euler numbers style):

[image]

Here what I want* (I think section titles and numbers are in palatino font while introduction is still in cm maybe because of \addcontentsline; I can fix it with `\section[{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont Introduction}]{Introduction}`):

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello there. Since your request is a little bit specific, I suggest you include a fully-compilable code in the question so that answerers can tune your code. Otherwise someone will have to workout a brand-new template and will be incompatible with yours.

Comment: There are no hooks in classicthesis.sty for different fonts for headlines, TOC etc. This means you'd have to redefine the commands that do typesetting. You may find some inspiration in the two sty files. Might be easier if you use xelatex or lualatex.